# Why sometimes when committing in TortoiseHg it shows no changes?

Tags: commit, tortoisehg, bitbucket

Sometimes when I change the project locally and want to commit it for some strange reason the commit window shows that no changes have been applied.

What could be the reason?

Comment: some more information on the nature of the changes would be most helpful. In the absence of that, I can only guess. Does your project have an `.hgignore` file? If so, check it for patterns matching the files that you modified. What extensions have you enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably ignored in the `.hgignore` file.